# Regular expression not finding a match

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match the word Salvage in this string, but the code is not picking it up. Where am I going wrong?

```
//String to match
String titleString = "<td><i><a href="/page/Vengeance2" title="Salary">Salvage</a></i></td>";

System.out.println(titleString);

//Template
String template = ">(.*)</a>";

//
Pattern p=Pattern.compile(template);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(titleString);

System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Comment: Don't use Regex to parse HTML/XML. Examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: "Where am I going wrong?" How do you know you are going wrong? Is there an error message? Does your code compile? Does it run, but do something you don't expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put a `matcher.find()` just before the `matcher.group(1)`.

The group takes the "Group from the last match". But as there was no match yet, you found nothing.